# Why is my nginx rewrite rule returning a 400?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a small issue I'm working around, where some static URLs are being created as, for example `/_static//images/logo.svg` rather than `/images/logo.svg`.

There's a proper fix coming out, but in  the meantime I need to make a rewrite rule, so `/_static//images/logo.svg` becomes `/images/logo.svg`.

I've added a rewrite rule as follows:

```
location / {  
    # Fix a stupid bug 
    # where static URLs are '/_static//images/logo.svg'
    # rather than '/images/logo.svg' on Linux
    rewrite ^(/_static/)(.*) $2 break;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Requesting `https://myapp.domain/_static//images/logo.svg` however still fails - with a 400 error. I can see the equest in `access.log`, but there's nothing in the `error.log`.

How can I make the rewrite rule work?

Comment: The `//` has been normalised to a single `/` by the time it reaches `rewrite`. Try: `rewrite ^(/_static)(/.*) $2 break;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you. If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` and `location` directives process a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which includes the merging of consecutive `/`s into a single `/` (unless [`merge_slashes`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes) is turned off).

As all URIs in Nginx have a leading `/`, I suspect that the lack of one in the rewritten URI is the cause of the 400 response.

Change the regular expression to address these two issues, for example:

```
rewrite ^(/_static)(/.*) $2 break;
```